# Find Laurent series expansion for $\frac{z}{2-z}$ on $2< \vert z \vert<\infty$.

Tags: complex-analysis, laurent-series

So I know I need to find the series which includes negative indices. I divided and get

$$\frac{z}{2-z}=-1+\frac{2}{2-z}=-1+\frac{1}{1-\frac{z}{2}}.$$

So for the power series I get

$$-1+\sum_{n=0}^\infty \bigg(\frac{z}{2}\bigg)^n.$$

So is this it?  OR...? Is $a_{-1}=-1$?

Comment: your expansion works for $|z/2|<1$, namely $|z|<2$. Try to factor $z$ in the denominator

Comment: @SineoftheTime from my original? So we want a $z$ in the denominator of the bottom?

Comment: $\frac z{2-z}=-\frac1{1-2/z}$, apply the geometric series and see its radius of convergence

Comment: I get $-\sum_{n=0}^\infty (\frac{2}{z})^n$ which converges when $\vert z \vert >2$. @SineoftheTime

Comment: looks good to me

Comment: Nice, thanks! @SineoftheTime

Comment: "I divided and get...". No, you didn't divide by anything...

Comment: @AdamRubinson I divided $z$ by $2-z$ …………

Comment: Lol, ok. There's no need to say that though....